# Full site view in mobile device in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, 51degrees

I am new to sitecore, how to use this query string: ?sc_device=%device name%&persisted=true so that i can keep full site view in my mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a redirect instead, based off a cookie or something that you will store if the user wants to switch to view full site in mobile device.

Comment: Please give me more detail.
I am using mobile device detector in sitecore and want to keep desktop view in mobile. From [link] (http://www.sitecore.net/nl-be/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/paul-caponetti/posts/2012/02/sitecore-mobile.aspx) i got that "Note that the Mobile Device Detector allows for a “View Full Site” link to have a query string variable for sc_device=default and persisted=true. This will show the site in whichever sc_device you choose for the rest of the session, but it will not allow you to switch to another device until you clear cookies or start a new session." How to do this?